# Import mulitple excelfiles with multiple sheets - issue with range

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

I'm trying to import multiple Excelfiles with multiple sheets.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

strFileName = "C:\SomeFile\File.xlsx"

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
Set colWorksheets = objWorkbook.Worksheets

For Each objWorksheet in colWorksheets 
    Set objRange = objWorksheet.UsedRange 
    strWorksheetName = objWorksheet.Name & "!" & objRange.Address(False, False) 
    objAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
        "Vulnerability", strFileName, True, strWorksheetName
Next
```

I have a problem with the range.  The variable strWorksheetName = "BE900!A1:L1634".

I get a runtime-error '3011'.  The "!" is replaced by "$" so the sheet isn't found.

Any ideas?

[image]

## ALL of my code

Public Function ImportFiles()
Dim strFolder As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strFile As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim strExtension As String
Dim lngFileType As Long
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strFullFileName As String
Dim varPieces As Variant

```
With Application.FileDialog(3) ' msoFileDialogFolderPicker
.AllowMultiSelect = True
.Title = "Please select one or more files"
.Initialfilename = "*.xls*"

If .Show Then
    strFullFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
Else
    MsgBox "No folder specified!", vbCritical
    Exit Function
End If
End With

strFile = Dir(strFolder)

Set db = CurrentDb()

strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xls*")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
strTable = DetermineTable(strFile)

strSQL = "UPDATE [" & strTable & "] SET FileName=[pFileName]" & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE FileName Is Null OR FileName='';"
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSQL)

varPieces = Split(strFile, ".")
strExtension = varPieces(UBound(varPieces))
Select Case strExtension
    Case "xls"
        lngFileType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9
    Case "xlsx", "xlsm"
        lngFileType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml
    Case "xlsb"
        lngFileType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12
End Select

Set objexcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objworkbook = objexcel.Workbooks.Open(strFullFileName)
Set colworksheets = objworkbook.Worksheets

For Each objWorksheet In colworksheets
    Set objRange = objWorksheet.UsedRange
    **strWorksheetName = objWorksheet.Name & "!" & objRange.Address(False, False)**
    'strWorksheetName = objRange.Address(0, 0, external:=True)
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
                TransferType:=acImport, _
                SpreadsheetType:=lngFileType, _
                tableName:=strTable, _
                FileName:=strFile, _
                HasFieldNames:=False, _
                **Range:=CStr(strWorksheetName)**
Next

colworksheets.Close
colworksheets = Nothing
objworkbook.Close
objworkbook = Nothing
objexcel.Close
objexcel = Nothing

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set tdf = db.TableDefs(strTable)

'Add the field to the table.
If FieldExistsInTable(strTable, "FileName") = True Then
    'Do nothing
Else
    tdf.Fields.Append tdf.CreateField("FileName", dbText, 255)
    'tdf.fields.append tdf.createField("SheetName", dbText, 255)
End If

'Supply the parameter value for the UPDATE and execute it ...
qdf.Parameters("pFileName").Value = strFile
qdf.Execute 'dbFailOnError

'Move to the next file
strFile = Dir
 Loop

Set fld = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
'rstTable.Close
Set rstTable = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Please, try replacing of `strWorksheetName` in `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` call with `objRange.Address(0, 0, external:=True)`.

Comment: I tried this, same issue, ! is replaced by $

Comment: OK. Now, try `"""" & strWorksheetName & """"`...

Comment: I doesn't make any difference when I test this.  When  I test just de code that imports the sheets of every file, it works.  But when I test it with the rest of my code the issue is still there.  I added all my code in the orginal question.

Comment: Since, you intend copying the `UsedRange`, please try only `objWorksheet.Name & "!"`. Theoretically, it should import all the sheet content. I cannot understand what's happening in your installation... What kind of localization do you have? Is it the standard English? I've also read somewhere that some systems need "$" separator instead of "!". You will maybe try it, too... I cannot reproduce your problem. Just for testing reason, try naming the used range of a specific sheet and use that name, instead of what you tried. If it works, we can adapt the code to create the named range on the fly.

Comment: Tried objWorksheet.Name & "!"
Also tried with objWorksheet.Name & "$"
Localization = English (Belgium)

I tried to run that piece of code, and then it runs fine, but not in my "bigger" function, so probably the error is there.
Thank you

Comment: I am trying to import multiple excelfiles (different layou) with multiple sheets, on import I add a field that contains the name of the file I imported.

Answer (score 0):

Macro does not have an error, works well in my PC.

You can try a PC restart.

I this does not help, you may define `strWorksheetName2`, replace `$` in `strWorksheetName` with `!`.  Then give it to access object.

Comment: The variable strWorksheetName is ok, it has the "!", so I can't replace the $ at that level.

Comment: can you change strWorksheetName with Cstr(strWorksheetName) in below line and give it a try. `objAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
        "Vulnerability", strFileName, True, Cstr(strWorksheetName)`

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilded the code from scratch in a new db, now it works.
Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: there is not much information about what do you mean by 'Rebuilded'. Some more details information are needed.